# Using Linq to get index of nearest point to another

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of Vector3 objects (representing points in 3d space), and another Vector3 object representing a cursor position.
I'd like to get the index in the array of the Vector3 closest to my cursor.

The distance between the cursor point and one of the points in the array is gotten like so..

```
  float Distance = (Points[0]-cursprpoint).magnitude;
```

I have already written a function to do this but it seems a little buggy.
I decided I will try using Linq instead cus I want to learn how to use it. I dont understand linq though and I'm hoping if someone posts an example of how to do this it will help me understand.

Comment: `Points.Max(x => (x - cursprpoint).magnitude)` or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float closestDistance = Points.Min(p => p.DistanceTo(otherPoint));
var pointWithClosestDistance = Points.Where(p => p.DistanceTo(otherPoint) == closestDistance).FirstOrDefault();
var indexOfPoint = Points.IndexOf(pointWithClosestDistance);
```

The `DistanceTo` method is left to the questioner as an exercise.

Edit: I agree with Daniel in the comments. This code will be incredibly inefficient so I do not recommend the above solution.

Comment: I would not recommend using this method. The first line takes O(n), the second line takes O(n) and the third line also takes O(n). You can get the index in one go with a couple more lines.

Comment: @Daniel I agree, this is definitely not efficient. I've updated my answer to denote that. I'm not an expert on these kinds of use cases.